# Using UPDATE and SET in temp table but values are not updating

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server v18.

I need to update a temp table and replace the values in Column_B that are equal to zero with the non-zero values, based on Column_A.

This is how the initial table looks like:

| Column_A | Column_B |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 0 |
| ABC | 123 |
| ABC | 0 |
| DEF | 456 |
| DEF | 0 |
| DEF | 0 |
| GHI | 123 |
| GHI | 0 |

This is what I am expecting the final table to look like:

| Column_A | Column_B |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 123 |
| ABC | 123 |
| ABC | 123 |
| DEF | 456 |
| DEF | 456 |
| DEF | 456 |
| GHI | 123 |
| GHI | 123 |

Here is the code that I have tried so far.

```
UPDATE #temp_table
SET Column_B = CASE 
                   WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM #temp_table AS t1
                                WHERE Column_B <> 0
                                  AND Column_A = t1.Column_A)
                       THEN Column_B 
                       ELSE 0 
               END
WHERE Column_B = 0;
```

This is the message from the above code:

```
5 rows affected
```

However, when I validate the results, the table remains unchanged.  The non-zero values have not been replaced.

I will appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: You do something like Update column b = column b, therefore the value does not change. You need to use a CTE, JOIN or correlated subquery to do such an update. What to do if multiple values except 0 occur in column B for the same value in column A? Which value should be set in this case?

Comment: *I am using SQL Server v.18* - No, you are not!

Comment: What if there are multiple different non-zero values

Comment: Telling us you use version 18 is like telling us the car you drive is a Sony, because that's the brand you see on the dashboard radio... fine for some, but you'd hope your mechanic knows better. The reality is there is no such thing as version 18 for SQL Server. There is a version 18 for SQL Server Management Studio, but this only provides an interface to the actual database engine. SSMS 18 can connect to _ANY_ version of SQL Server from 2005 all the up to the latest 2022, and even to non-SQL Server databases. It therefore tells us **NOTHING** about what database version you're using.

Comment: Thanks, Jonas.  Having multiple values in Column_B would be an unlikely scenario but, you are correct, I need to account for that.  If multiple values are present, I will have to select the correct value, which would be the first record written, based on a DateTime column.

Could you provide a sample code with a join or correlated subquery?

Comment: Is this better?  Version v18.12.1

Comment: run: `SELECT @@VERSION` to see the actual version :)

Comment: @GLo No, it's not. That's still the version of SQL Server Management Studio which has **absolutely nothing at all** to do with the version of SQL Server that is running your code. You want `SELECT @@version`.

Comment: Thank you, @siggemannen and Joel for the clarification.  The version is:  Microsoft SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer follows the requirement you described in comments:

> I will have to select the correct value, which would be the first record written, based on a DateTime column

I think you will do better to edit your question and adjust the sample data rather than writing this as a comment that people might not read.

Anyway, this query using `FIRST_VALUE` will fetch the first of Column B for each value in Column A which is not `NULL` and not `0`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  Column_A,
  FIRST_VALUE(column_B) IGNORE NULLS OVER
    (PARTITION BY column_A ORDER BY yourdate) AS updateValue
FROM t
WHERE Column_B <> 0;
```

The `ORDER BY yourdate` clause covers your requirement to take "the first record written" because this is the row having the earliest date.
Above query can be used in the update command:

```
WITH updateValues AS
(SELECT DISTINCT
  Column_A,
  FIRST_VALUE(column_B) IGNORE NULLS OVER
    (PARTITION BY column_A ORDER BY yourdate) AS updateValue
FROM t
WHERE Column_B <> 0)
UPDATE t 
  SET t.Column_B = u.updateValue
  FROM t 
  INNER JOIN updateValues u
  ON t.Column_A = u.Column_A
  WHERE t.Column_B = 0;
```

The `WHERE` clause in the update command makes sure to update those rows only where `Column B` is `0`.

See this [sample fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5X2rHAtJ).

It shows the result for some data similar to yours, but extended by some other rows.
Thus, it points out how this idea works.

Comment: Thank you, Jonas.  This is perfect.  Thank you for providing the code along with detailed explanations and advice on how to use this forum more efficiently. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Ignore nulls requires sql server 2022 though :)

Comment: @siggemannen Valid point. We can generally add the condition `Column_B IS NULL` or ... `NOT NULL` to the `WHERE` clauses instead. Seems by the way like `NULL` values don't occur at all, so we can just remove it and leave the rest at it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'#TEMP_TABLE',N'U')IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE TEMPDB..#TEMP_TABLE

CREATE TABLE #TEMP_TABLE
(
   Column_A CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
   Column_B SMALLINT NOT NULL
)
INSERT #TEMP_TABLE(Column_A,Column_B)
   SELECT 'ABC',0 UNION ALL
   SELECT 'ABC',    123 UNION ALL
   SELECT 'ABC',    0 UNION ALL
   SELECT 'DEF',    456 UNION ALL
   SELECT 'DEF',    0 UNION ALL
   SELECT 'DEF',    0 UNION ALL
   SELECT 'GHI',    123 UNION ALL
   SELECT 'GHI',    0

 UPDATE T SET
   T.Column_B=X.MAX_B
 FROM #TEMP_TABLE AS T
 JOIN
 (
   SELECT Z.Column_A,MAX(Z.Column_B)AS MAX_B
      FROM #TEMP_TABLE AS Z
   GROUP BY  Z.Column_A
 ) X ON T.Column_A=X.Column_A

 SELECT * FROM #TEMP_TABLE

 DROP TABLE #TEMP_TABLE;
```

Please try this query with correlated UPDATE (update...join)

Comment: Thank you, Stu and Sergey for your help.  Both your answers solved my problem.  I appreciate your help.